# how can I increase Cookie Expire Time Span?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-identity

I use Identity and Cookie authentication. But my login user time is less than ExpireTimeSpan that I set in my StartupAut file.

`   public partial class Startup
{
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
app.CreatePerOwinContext(SurveyContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext(UserService.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext(SigninService.Create);

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
    }
}`
```

then user redirect to loginpage less than 120 minutes.

Thank for your help.

I want to increase login time.